# Test Case for Export to Excel functionality

Tags: testing, grails, case, export-to-excel

I have an export to excel functionality in my application. I am to write a test case for teh same.

Any Inputs??Sample Code??

Heres my action code.

When the User clicks on "Download to excel" on the page, below export action is called. I am to test this functionality.

```
def export={

    def playerId=session["playerId"]

    //Calls calculateId, runs an sql query and returns a List
    tuneInstanceList = tuneService.calculateId(playerId)

    if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){
        response.contentType =     ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=tune.${params.extension}")


        exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, tuneInstanceList,[:], [:])
    }

    [tuneInstanceList: tuneInstanceList]

    session.flush()
    session.clear()
}
```

Edited:

As per Robberts' answer wrote an integration test as below.

```
    class BinaryOutputControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase { 
    void testExportToExcel() { 
    def controller = new TuneController() 

    controller.session.playerID = "ABG65" 
    controller.params.format = "xls" 
    controller.params.extension = "xls" 

    def model = controller.export() 

    assert controller.response.status == 200 
    assert controller.response.contentAsByteArray.size() == 167336 
    assert controller.response.getContentType() \ 
        == "application/vnd.ms-excel" 
    assert controller.response.getHeader("Content-disposition") \ 
        == "attachment; filename=tune.${controller.params.extension}" 

    assert model.tuneInstanceList.size() 
    assert controller.session.valueNames.size() == 0 
}
```

}

However, I am getting the following error. Thoughts?

TuneController.groovy:169 refers to line in export action viz.

```
exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, tuneInstanceList,[:], [:])
```

TuneControllerTests.groovy:264 refers to a line in the tests written viz.

```
def model = tuneController.export()
```

Below is the error that I am getting.

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cbf864b.export()
at de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportService$export.call(Unknown Source)
at pride.TuneController$_closure5.doCall(TuneController.groovy:169)
at pride.TuneController$_closure5.doCall(TuneController.groovy)
at pride.TuneControllerTests.testExportToExcel(TuneControllerTests.groovy:264)
Caused by: de.andreasschmitt.export.exporter.ExporterNotFoundException: No exporter     found for type: xls
at de.andreasschmitt.export.exporter.DefaultExporterFactory.createExporter    (DefaultExporterFactory.groovy:56)
at de.andreasschmitt.export.exporter.ExporterFactory$createExporter$0.callCurrent    (Unknown Source)
at de.andreasschmitt.export.exporter.DefaultExporterFactory.createExporter    (DefaultExporterFactory.groovy:23)
at de.andreasschmitt.export.exporter.ExporterFactory$createExporter.call(Unknown     Source)
at de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportService.export(ExportService.groovy:19)
at de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c1bbbb10.invoke()
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
at de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cbf864b.export()
at de.andreasschmitt.export.ExportService$export.call(Unknown Source)
at pride.TuneController$_closure5.doCall(TuneController.groovy:169)
at pride.TuneController$_closure5.doCall(TuneController.groovy)
at pride.TuneControllerTests.testExportToExcel(TuneControllerTests.groovy:264)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:268)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.call(_GrailsTest_groovy)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:225)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1_closure21.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:184)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:171)
at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:101)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No     bean     named 'xlsExporter' is defined
at de.andreasschmitt.export.exporter.DefaultExporterFactory.createExporter            (DefaultExporterFactory.groovy:34)
```

Comment: Test Cases are usually derived from Use Cases, not just out of thin air ...

Comment: Thats right Belisarius. have updated my action code as well.Please take a look.

Comment: [-1] Questioner expanded their question far beyond original scope. Answerer responded, but questioner hasn't come back on that.

Comment: @robbert: My Bad...Dint c this for quite some time....let me try this out...Sumhw i dnt get a pop up when someone repkies/comments on my qn......Thats Bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the technical level, it has to be decided whether to use an *[integration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing)* or a *[unit](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.2%20Integration%20Testing)* test.

In Grails unit tests, dependency injection (of services, for example) is not available (however, the test class can provide the controller with dependencies, manually). Any other types of instrumentation, including database access, aren't available, too.
In my personal opinion, it's better to write finer-grained (unit) tests with controllers; however, if you don't want to *mock* your services, integration tests do as well.

The following sample code is an integration test (but a unit test is not *that* different):

```
class BinaryOutputControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testExportToExcel() {
        def controller = new BinaryOutputController()

        controller.session.playerID = "somePlayerID"
        controller.params.format = "xls"
        controller.params.extension = "xls"

        def model = controller.export()

        assert controller.response.status == 200
        assert controller.response.contentAsByteArray.size() == 167336
        assert controller.response.getContentType() \
            == "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        assert controller.response.getHeader("Content-disposition") \
            == "attachment; filename=tune.${controller.params.extension}"

        assert model.tuneInstanceList.size()
        assert controller.session.valueNames.size() == 0
    }
}
```

The sample code shows that you can access the [GrailsHttpSession](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsHttpSession.html) and the controller's `params` object to initialize values.

Next, you'd call the controllers *action method* and retrieve its return values.

In your testing *assertions*, you can access the controller's [MockHttpServletResponse](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html) to query for response values. Again, the [GrailsHttpSession](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsHttpSession.html) object is available as well as the *model* returned by the controller's *action method*.

Obviously, you need to identify use cases; however, these are some technical basics. You should also write failing tests using the `shouldFail { ... }` closure. And look at the links I've provided as they give you hints on additional options.

---

**EDIT:** As per your further inquiry:

First, let your `ExporterNotFoundException` `extend RuntimeException` (not the *checked* `Exception`) in order to avoid that [`UndeclaredThrowableException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html). Alternatively (not preferred), add the `throws ExporterNotFoundException` clause to your `DefaultExporterFactory.createExporter(..)` method definition. - Groovy's all based on `RuntimeException`s, but you still need to explicitely declare *checked* `Exception`s using the `throws` clause.

Second, check whether your `ExportService` is capable of handling the "xls" `format` (look for the cause of that `ExporterNotFoundException`). Apparently, it is not.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for Robbbert....I get your point totally on identifying the use cases and get going.
However, there is one query here. In my controller, in export action, in the last line, exportService is called. Here my integration test is giving me issues. I have updated my original question with the error codes. Could u plz check?

Answer (score 0):

What belisarius is hinting at is that we can't really provide what you are looking for.  For test cases (or do you mean test data?) you should really be looking at the use cases of the system.  The use cases should be known before coding (ie, how will my users be using this application).  You or someone on your team should know how this is supposed to work and should be able to help you find what you are looking for.  If you or a team member doesn't know how this is supposed to work, find someone who does; we (the general IT public) certainly can't help.

Once you know how it is supposed to work, you should be able to find/craft sample data to work with.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I hear what you are saying. I was actually looking for a basic model to start with. For eg. Here in my case the use case is to check whether the excel has some data. The data details are not important. But just the fact that the excel is getting populated would be fine.